# Sort a data grid based on a specified column

Tags: winforms, sorting

Developed a winform project using VB 2008. I'm using a .xls sheet as source. My appln has 7 columns and unspecified rows. I want to sort all the columns based on a specified column and allot a serial number as per the sorted order. If two items in the specified column are same we should consider another column for the equal items and sort them in that order. plz help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SortableBindingList

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx